# how Dart Reading input from the console in terminal

Tags: flutter, dart, user-input

how it worked

Dart Reading input from the console in terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the command-line arguments passed to a Dart program through the main function's parameter.

The main function takes an optional List parameter, which represents the command-line arguments passed to the program.

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Number of arguments: ${arguments.length}');

  for (final String arg in arguments) {
    print(arg);
  }
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$ dart main.dart arg1 arg2 arg3
```